# Threads when looking recursively in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a graphical browser to learn and right now I'm with the searcher, but a few problems have arised which I am unable to solve.

The main program freezes up while it's waiting for the search to end. How could I fix this? What I want is the main program to keep running while the search is done in the background.

Another thing I'd like to ask is, I'm making a thread but it's really slow, I'd like to create several threads that work in parallel and so it takes less time to search everything (but with a limit of simultaneous threads so it doesn't drain too much processing power).

This is the code I have

```
FilenameFilter textoFiltrado = new FilenameFilter() {
 @Override
 public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
      String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
      return StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(lowercaseName, nombreBuscado);
  }
};

ArrayList<File> archivos = new ArrayList();
Thread buscar = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
   buscador.setEnabled(false);
   archivos.addAll(u.busqueda(new File(ruta), textoFiltrado, true));
}

});

buscar.start();
buscar.join();
```

And this is the method being called

```
public static Collection busqueda(File directory, FilenameFilter filter, boolean recurse) {

Vector files = new Vector();

File[] entries = directory.listFiles();

for (File entry : entries) {

    String s = entry.getName();

    if (s.indexOf(".") > 0) {

        s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("."));

    }

    if (filter == null || filter.accept(directory, s)) {
        files.add(entry);
    }


    if (recurse && entry.isDirectory()) {
        files.addAll(busqueda(entry, filter, recurse));
    }
}

return files;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Java Standart Edition (SE) 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can create a class that implements

```
Callable<Vector<File>>
```

Such as...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class ThreadFiles implements Callable<Vector<File>> {

    @Override
    public Vector<File> call() throws Exception {
        File[] files = new File("C:/PathToFiles").listFiles();
        Vector<File> vectorFiles = new Vector<File>();

        for (File file : files) {
            vectorFiles.add(file);
        }
        return vectorFiles; 
    }
}
```

And then when calling that class evaluate your files from the thread:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Vector;

public class CallThreadFiles {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        final ThreadFiles  task = new ThreadFiles();                
        Vector<File> files = null;

        try {
            files = task.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (File f: files) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());            
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 you can use the [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) instread of `File` and (parallel) [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to accomplish what you want. The [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class has a [`walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) method that will traverse through the files and subfolders.

When the `CompletableFuture` has finished you can use its [`thenAccept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-) method to chain the update of the user interface. Be aware that this code is *not* on the user interface thread so you need to schedule the update of the UI on the UI thread again. If you use [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) (which you should imho) you do that by using the [`Platform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html) class. If you are sticking to Swing it will be `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

```
Path directory = ....;
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Files.walk(directory)
                             .parallelStream()
                             .filter(p -> /* your filter condition goes here */)
                             .collect(Collectors.asList()))
                  .thenAccept(l -> Platform.runLater(() -> /* update UI with List<Path>*/);
```